# Adding an attached behavior to an ItemsPanelTemplate

Tags: wpf, silverlight, xaml, mvvm, attached-properties

I'm trying to add behavior to my ItemsPanelTemplate where all the items are collapsed except the one on top hence I've specified a StackPanel with a custom attached behavior.

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding ViewModels}">
    <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <StackPanel my:ElementUtilities.CollapseAllButLast="True"/>
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
</ItemsControl>
```

The problem is that when the LayoutUpdated event handler is called within my behavior the sender is always null. Why is this?

```
public static class ElementUtilities
{
    public static readonly DependencyProperty CollapseAllButLastProperty = DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached
        ("CollapseAllButLast", typeof(bool), typeof(ElementUtilities), new PropertyMetadata(false, CollapseAllButLastChanged));

    static void CollapseAllButLastChanged(DependencyObject o, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        StackPanel sp = o as StackPanel;
        if (sp != null)
        {
            if (e.NewValue != null && (bool)e.NewValue)
                sp.LayoutUpdated += sp_LayoutUpdated;
            else
                sp.LayoutUpdated -= sp_LayoutUpdated;
        }
        else
            throw new InvalidOperationException("The attached CollapseAllButLast property can only be applied to StackPanel instances.");
    }

    public static bool GetCollapseAllButLast(StackPanel stackPanel)
    {
        if (stackPanel == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("stackPanel");
        return (bool)stackPanel.GetValue(CollapseAllButLastProperty);
    }

    public static void SetCollapseAllButLast(StackPanel stackPanel, bool collapseAllButLast)
    {
        if (stackPanel == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("stackPanel");
        stackPanel.SetValue(CollapseAllButLastProperty, collapseAllButLast);
    }

    static void sp_LayoutUpdated(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // Collapse all but last element
        StackPanel sp = (StackPanel)sender;     // This is always null
        for (int i = 0; i < sp.Children.Count - 1; i++)
        {
            UIElement l = sp.Children[i];
            l.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
        }
        sp.Children[sp.Children.Count - 1].Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkelement.layoutupdated%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) documentation of LayoutUpdated event -

> When you handle LayoutUpdated, do not rely on the sender value. **For
>   LayoutUpdated, sender is always null**, regardless of where the handler
>   is attached. This is to prevent handlers from assigning any meaning to
>   sender, such as implying that it was that specific element that raised
>   the event out of the visual tree.

Instead you can hook to `loaded event` -

```
if (e.NewValue != null && (bool)e.NewValue)
   sp.Loaded += sp_Loaded;
else
   sp.Loaded -= sp_Loaded;
```